# How do I use mongoDb to update value on my database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am building a CRUD app using monogoDb and Reactjs, I need to pass my updated value to replace the old one. I am able to get the ID but I can't seem to pass the value correctly.

jsx for the update input.

```
               ...<input
                type="text"
                placeholder="New food name"
                onChange={(event) => {
                    setNewFoodName(event.target.value)
                }}/>
            <button onClick={()=>updateInput(item._id)}>Update</button>
```

my update function

```
function updateInput(id) {
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/update/${id}`, {
        di: id,
        newFoodName: foodName
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r)
    })
    console.log(newFoodName)
}
```

my backend using mongodb.

```
app.patch('/update/:id', (req,res) =>{
const updatedFood = req.body

//console.log(updates.newFoodName)
if(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)){
    db.collection('foods')
        .updateOne({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: updatedFood})
        .then(result =>{
            res.status(200).json(result)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(500).json({error: "Unable to update item"})
        })
}else{
    res.status(500).json({err: "Cannot update request"})
}
})
```

Comment: `di: id`? ... typo or intentional?

Comment: You need to destructure your `req.body` to match the item schema so Mongo knows what fields you are updating. In your update function, should `di:` instead be `id`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was my bad. Let me try and change it. But I still don't think it will fix my issue. I am already getting the ID of the specific document I want to update, changing the value to match that of the one from the updated input field is my concern. once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to fix it from the front-end.

```
function updateInput(id) {
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/update/${id}`, {
        id: id,
        // newFoodName: newFoodName,
        foodName: newFoodName    // PASS IN THE foodName to the newFoodName
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r)
    })
    console.log(newFoodName)
}
```